# Why assign MAC and IP addresses on Bridge interface

Tags: linux, ip, bridge, mac-address

Say I create a bridge interface on linux (`br0`) and add to it some interfaces (`eth0`, `tap0`, etc.). My understanding is that this interface act like a virtual switch with all its interfaces/ports that I add to it.

What is the meaning of assigning a MAC and an IP address to that interface? Does the interface act as an additional port on the switch/bridge which allows other ports to access the host machine?

I have seen some pages talk about assigning an IP address to a bridge. Is the MAC assignation implied (or automatic)?

Comment: This is a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86056/64386)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because a bridge is an ethernet device it needs a MAC address.  A linux bridge can originate things like spanning-tree protocol frames, and traffic like that needs an origin MAC address.

A bridge does not *require* an ip address.  There are many situations in which you won't have one.  However, in many cases you *may* have one, such as:

- When the bridge is acting as the default gateway for a group of containers or virtual machines (or even physical interfaces).  In this case it needs an ip address (because routing happens at the IP layer).
- When your "primary" NIC is a member of the bridge, such that the bridge is your connectivity to the outside world.  In this case, rather than assigning an ip address to (for example) `eth0`, you would assign it to the bridge device instead.

If the bridge is *not* required for ip routing, then it doesn't need an ip address.  Examples of this situation include:

- When the bridge is being used to create a private network of devices with no external connectivity, or with external connectivity provided through a device other than the bridge.

Comment: "Because a bridge is an ethernet device it needs a MAC address." Why? The devices connected to the bridges do have MAC addresses. But I don't think the bridge itself need one. As for the rest of the answer, does that means that the bridge interface act as an additional "port" on the bridge which allows other ports to access the host machine?

Comment: The bridge is able to originate Ethernet frames, so it needs an address.  Re: the second part of your question...sure.

Comment: But is it mandatory that the bridge interface has a MAC address? I mean, a physical switch does not have to have a MAC address to do its job, does it? So I would think that the interface does not require one either.

Comment: A simple bridge is effectively a two-port switch, so it does not necessarily need any addresses. A simple bridge does not originate frames, it just receives a frame on one port and either forwards it on the other port, or drops it.

Comment: "such that the bridge is your connectivity to the outside world." Why? Why can't the primary NIC be still the connection to the outside world? Real hardware bridges also keep the IP address of the real link partners connected to them. Why not the linux wirtual bridge?

Answer (score 15):

The bridge device listed with your other networking devices does not represent the virtual bridge, it represents a virtual NIC that is connected to the bridge. If you had a physical bridge connected with physical networking devices, you wouldn't see the physical bridge listed in your networking devices either -- but you would see your NIC that is connected to the bridge, which of course has its own MAC address like any other network device.

Assigning an IP adress to the bridge device (which, again, is actually a virtual NIC connected to the virtual bridge) allows your host device to route packets to the subnet created by the bridge and all of the devices attached to it. Neat!

While networking device tools such as `iproute2` (with the `ip link` and `ip addr` commands) allow you to see the virtual NIC attached to the bridge, it is also possible to see the virtual bridge itself with the `brctl` program. The `brctl show` command will list all bridges and their attached interfaces. Here is an example using `iproute` and `brctl` with Linux bridges and tuntaps:

```
# ip link add br0 type bridge
# ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap
# ip tuntap add dev tap1 mode tap
# ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev br0
# ip addr add 10.0.0.2/24 broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev tap0
# ip addr add 10.0.0.3/24 broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev tap1
# brctl addif br0 tap0
# brctl addif br0 tap1
# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.2e22e593fe8c       no              tap0
                                                        tap1
# ip addr show to 10.0.0.0/24
11: br0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.2/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global tap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: tap1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.3/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global tap1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Note that what is listed under "interfaces" in the output of `brctl show` are the *other* interafces attached to the bridge, in addition to the `br0` interface that was automatically added when the bridge was created. (I guess Linux doesn't allow creating a virtual bridge with no attached devices, and bridges with no devices are automatically destroyed.) For the record, I haven't researched this in the kernel, nor am I a networking expert. I posted this because it seems to convincingly explain the rather confusing implementation of virtual bridges in Linux. I do not believe that the virtual bridges themselves even have MAC addresses.

Comment: actually you should use iproute2's `bridge` command to handle advanced cases not handled already by `ip link`. `brctl` is part of the obsolete tools like `ifconfig`. For simple bridge cases, `ip link add ... type bridge` and `ip link set ... master br0` handles it all. There's also `ip link show type bridge_slave` or `ip link show type bridge` (and a few cases with `bridge link show`)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, the bridge interface acts as an additional port.

After `man 5 systemd.netdev`:

> A bridge device is a software switch, and each of its slave devices and the bridge itself are ports of the switch.

Comment: I believe a port on a switch is a transparent device on L2 and L3 it does not have a necessairly have to have a MAC or IP. if a switch runs in promiscuous mode it only stores the mac addresses of the divices connected. There is no reason for the bridge to have mac addresses.

Answer (score 4):

The `br0` and `virbr0` interfaces listed by `ip addr` and `ip link` are tap interfaces that connect the host to the `br0` bridge and `virbr0` bridge respectively. This overloading of names can certainly be confusing.

So what is `virbr0-nic`?

This was not part of the original question but I'll add my 2 cents here since this confused me in the past. `virbr0-nic` is a dummy interface whose MAC address is used by the `virbr0` bridge as its own mac address.  This always-present interface is there to prevent `virbr0`'s MAC address from changing when ports are dynamically added or removed from the bridge. The host does not send any traffic out the `virbr0-nic` interface.

See https://backreference.org/2010/07/28/linux-bridge-mac-addresses-and-dynamic-ports and https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2012-September/msg00038.html for an explanation.